# Will I lose my job by saying I can't work certain hours?

Tags: professionalism, communication, hiring-process, scheduling

So I've been trying incredibly hard to try to get this job since before the pandemic and I am finaly able to start working after completing a slew of trainings.

The problem is I'm still in highschool and even though I am doing online schooling most days, I am expected to be logged on from the hours of 8am-4pm. The same hours my boss scheduled me to work.

I told her that I could work anytime after school, but I am afraid that there was a miscommunication and she thought I could work those hours.

Will I get fired for telling her I can't? I also have to take the SATs during the time she scheduled me for my first day of work, which I told her saying that I could work later hours that day of its OK but she hasn't gotten back to me yet. Basically, how do I go about politely explaining the mistake and will I lose this job because I cant work the hours she scheduled me because I have to do  school?

Comment: Location ?  Country makes a difference to the relevant law.  Off the top of my head I wonder if your working hours are even legal as it sounds like you are a minor still in (probably) compulsory education.  Trying to coerce a minor to work during school or exam hours would certainly be illegal in my country.

Answer (score 16):

> Will I get fired for telling her I can't?

Only your boss can answer that!

> Basically, how do i go about politely explaining the mistake ?

More than polite, be clear. Tell them clearly these are your school hours and you cannot work in these slots. Apologise for any confusion or miscommunication earlier but convey your schedule conflict without any ambiguity.

Your primary concern still seems to be whether or not you will get fired and I think you should not bother about it. I am not sure about the legal requirement but sacrificing school or SAT for your high-school job does not seem like a good idea. That should be a deal breaker anyway. Instead put your effort in finding a new job (if at all your manager decides to fire you).

Comment: Agreed.  Getting fired might be scary, especially for someone still in school and (presumably) not that experienced in the work force, but when you're that young, getting good grades will take you farther than any single job.  Explain your position clearly and hope for the best, but at this point in OP's life, getting fired from *one* job is better than taking a hit on the academic side.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible you may, and that's unfair (but life). It's more likely you'll get moved to a shift that suites your availability better. You probably are free nights and weekends - that's when you should be working.

Talking to your boss ASAP to get it fixed is the best solution for both of you. There's no magic way of phrasing this that will make it right; I'd go with "I have school - I thought I mentioned this in my application. I'm willing to work any other time mornings, nights, weekends, whatever you need, I just can't do these middle of day hours until (school holiday date)".

If you do lose your job because of this, The parting of ways will be better the sooner you have this conversation - do it now and they may just defer your start date till school holidays, delay until after your start date and they'll be angry.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what kind of job you were hired for but something like this should work:

> Hi boss,
>
> I just received the schedule and I think I might have a conflict. It seems that you have scheduled me for 8-4 on weekdays but I attend high school during those hours.
>
> Are there any available hours outside of my school time?
>
> Thank you

This will at least open up the conversation and your boss will say something like:

> These are the only hours, take it or leave it.

or

> Oh, yes I forgot that you are in high school, let me check what else is available.

or

> What?! You never mentioned that you're in high school!

If the last scenario happens then that is not a boss that you want to work for.